# Specifying parameter grid for regression model

Tags: random-forest, hyperparameter-tuning, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am working with more than one dataset. So, I have to test my Random Forest Model over 4 datasets. The parameter grid I am taking for dataset D1 is not producing good results for dataset D2 and so on. I have tried multiple range of parameters but none is working for all datasets. Please suggest if their is any empirical/ analytical way by which I can set a common parameter grid for all datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping these data sets separate? If you want to keep them separate, then you could use these data sets as your folds for k-fold cross validation. Then choose the parameter set which leads to the best average performance.

Comment: All these datasets have different dimensions, i.e. no two datasets have common features. So I can't club them together.